# Regex to get all content after the first closing html tag in java

Tags: java, regex

Regex to get all the content after the first closing tag ">" encountered before

```
"<a href " till the end.
```

How do I get that? I'm not good at regex :/

eg:

```
<img class="abc" src="abc.jpg"> blah blah blah&nbsp;<a 
href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki">abc defg hijk lmnop</a>&nbsp; blah
```

Expected output:

blah blah blah [abc defg hijk lmnop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki) blah

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
htmls = htmls.replaceAll(".*?>(?=.*?<a href)", "");
```

It means remove everything until the closing tag, which is before the first `<a href`

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you cannot parse HTML with a Regex because HTML is not a regular language. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for a full discussion.